# iPhone X Stuck on Control Center

Tags: iphone, control-center

For a small while now, my phone (an iPhone X on iOS 13) has sadly been stuck on the Control Center to where I can’t really use either one in any way. I’ve tried to use a function or go back; turn the phone off; or activate Siri; but aside from managing to get something flashing in the background, getting the Wifi thing to turn green, or being able to lock and unlock the phone (at which the Center pops right back up, no lock screen shown) nothing. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Update: Looks like some things still run, but in the background where they can’t be managed due to the “wall” of the stuck Control Center. Managed to activate Siri and get the flashlight on and off through voice, but can’t do much more, as she “thinks” my phone’s still locked despite it seeming to be semi-unlocked (I think?)

Answer (score 1):

Force-restart your iPhone:

> Press and quickly release the Volume Up button. Press and quickly release the Volume Down button. Then press and hold the Side button until you see the Apple logo.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201412